# Is there any tool for showing relationships between two entities

Tags: neo4j, relationship, entity-relationship

I'm looking for a tool that could fit to the next task.

For example, user selects in interface entity University and types in some id-s for searching it and gets the result of universities list related to his request, then he does the same with entity Person and at last he types the maximum relationship length. The result of his request is some graph of relationships for example.

```
(: Person) -[: IS_BROTHER] ->(: Person) -[: IS_STUDENT] ->(: University)
```

or he might get several results that fits relationship length

I'm not very experienced with neo4j and don't know if there is any tool to fit this task. Or any other tool not related to neo4j would be fine, but I doubt that sql works fine with relationship search. Thanks.

Edited 
I'm loking for user friendly tool that will generate this request without user knowing chypher language at all

Comment: [Cypher](http://neo4j.com/developer/cypher-query-language/) is the query language for neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Cypher query that returns all paths that are at most 5 relationships deep between any `Person` whose ID is in a given list and any `University` whose ID is in another list:

```
MATCH path=(p:Person)-[*..5]->(u:University)
WHERE ID(p) IN [1,22,333] AND ID(u) IN [2,444,192,678]
RETURN path;
```

You could use the [neo4j Browser](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tools-webadmin.html) to see the paths.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm loking for user friendly tool that will generate this request without user knowing chypher language at all.